# SQL Data type query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2008, is it faster to do a query to find `uniqueidentifier` or can you use any of the string data types, like `nvarchar` without any significant penalty?  Note that I'm not talking about a primary key field, just any old field

Comment: If the column's not indexed, it's a table-scan either way. Large values in `nvarchar(max)` might incur a performance penalty due to being stored outside the table though.

Comment: Are you talking about a part of a condition or just purely reading the data from that field?

Comment: I'm talking about a straight SELECT query

Comment: @Blorgbeard  I suppose you're right.  Some part of me thought that `uniqueidentifier` would automatically create some kind of special index but I suppose that's not true.

Answer (score 0):

The different data types have different impacts on performance. Depending on the context, some data types can be more advantageous than others. Be sure to consider what indexes are created because they can have significant impact upon how fast a query runs.